# laravel redirect before csv download

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I have checkboxes and button in the view.

When no checkbox is checked, I wanna redirect and show errors in the view.

I have CsvController class, and functions below all belong to it. When I push the button, checkbox values send to CsvControllers, and csvDownload function will be called

But other than `dd()` I cant stop downloading csv.

```
public function isValidCsvData() {
    $arrayKey = array_keys($this->request->all());

    //リストが未選択になっていないかのチェック
    if (!preg_grep("/^list/", $arrayKey)) {
        //含まれていない場合
        return redirect('csv_export')->with([
            'listErr' => 'リストを選択してください',
            'error' => 'リストを選択してください',
        ]);
    }
~~~
```

I run this in the constructor

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->request = $request;

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->isValidCsvData();
    }
}
```

The csvDownload function is like this

```
public function csvDownload() {
    $headers = [
        "Content-type" => "text/csv",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=" . $fileName,
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0",
    ];

    $callback = function () use ($csvData) {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        foreach ($csvData as $row) {
            mb_convert_variables('SJIS-win', 'UTF-8', $row);
            fputcsv($handle, $row);
        }

        fclose($handle);
    };
    return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
}
```

Why it can't return response even if I can `dd()` and catch the error??

Comment: It's not clear what your view looks like, what controller does the form in the view post to, which method in the controller handles the request, what class does the constructor belong to...

Comment: @Matey I have CsvController class, and functions above all belong to it. When I push the button, checkbox values send to CsvControllers, and csvDownload function will be called